# PHP website ERROR 500

Tags: php

I developed some php pages on the XAMPP environment and It worked perfectly but when I moved it to a production server(ubuntu 10.04 apache2),there were two pages that were throwing error.

I added the error report script and this is what i got

```
Warning: require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/globalgoal/include/signallogic.php on line 2 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/globalgoal/include/signallogic.php on line 2
```

I installed the PEAR package in ubuntu server.

This is the actual code:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

function mailing($context, $user) // Email Notification function
{

    $w = date('W')-1;
    $leader=array();
    $con=mysqli_connect("10.9.245.211","root","password","qa");
    $sql="SELECT firstname, lastname, access_id FROM user where username = '$user' "; 
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $access_id= $row['access_id'];
            $firstname= $row['firstname'];
            $lastname= $row['lastname'];

        }

    $name=$firstname . " " . $lastname;// Analyst name

    // Get the initiative lead name
    $sql="SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM user where access_id = $access_id and leader=1 "; 
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        array_push($leader,$row['email']);

    }
    $leaderemail="";    
    for($i=0;$i< count($leader);$i++)
    {
        $leaderemail .=$leader[$i] . " , ";


    }
     $leaderemail=str_replace(",",">, <",$leaderemail);
     $from = xxxx@ddd.com;
     $to = abc@azx.com;

     $subject = "Weekly Analyst Inputs - Week " . $w ;
     $body = "Hi,<br/><br/>Thank you so much for inputting numbers for week " . $w . ".<br/><br/> These numbers were successfully submitted by <b>" . $name . "</b><br/><br/>" . $context ;

     $host = "used corp details"; // SMTP server for eBay email
     $username = ""; // No Auth
     $password = "";

     $MIME="1.0";
     $type="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    // =================No need to modify below===================
     $headers = array ('From' => $from,
       'To' => $to,
       'Subject' => $subject,
       'MIME-VERSION'=>$MIME,
       'Content-Type'=>$type
       );
     $smtp = @Mail::factory('smtp',
       array ('host' => $host,
         'auth' => false,
         'username' => $username,
         'password' => $password));

     $mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

     if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) {
       echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
      } else {
       echo("<p>The input results are successfully sent to the initiative lead analysts.</p>");
```

Comment: Did you check that all the files you include or otherwise use in your code are correct? Remember that Windows is **not** case-sensitive while Ubuntu is. `Mail.php` is different from `mail.php`. Enabling error reporting would be beneficial if you just get error 500

Comment: Error is pretty much self-explanatory - see if `Mail.php` is in `/var/www/globalgoal/include` or not.

Comment: I can see the page now ,but the mailing function is not working.

Comment: Did you try this command find / --name Mail.php. If you don't find it that means that you just install PEAR but the mail library is missing and you'll have to install it

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the PEAR package class is not seen correctly.Check the `/usr/share/pear` path to see if it contains the class, also check permissions on the folder

Comment: There is no folder called usr/share/pear

Comment: Everything works apart from the mailing function and worst part is I dont see any error .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will help you to find the error.